# How to locate database path in ojdbc7 jar file (JAVA)

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

Currently for our Java application we are pointing it to a 12c oracle database and we are planing to upgrade the database and point our java application to it.

Is there a hardcoded parameter in ojdbc7 that I can modify to point to the new database.

As you know ojdbc7 has many files inside, so it’s hard to check file by file

Comment: ojdbc is just the driver, it does not have any pointer to the database. Your java program that uses jdbc gives it the pointer.

Comment: So I should check jdbc and modify it’s pointer to the new database?

Comment: no. check your application, not jdbc. jdbc is _just_ the driver; it contains _no_ connection information. All of the connection info comes from inside your application configuration or code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a hardcoded parameter in ojdbc7 that I can modify to point to the new database.

No. JDBC is just a driver, it does not know where any database is. Do **NOT** modify any of the JDBC files.

Your application tells the driver where the database is so you need to update your application.